# text based python game with functions, function patameters and global variables

Tags: python

I am making a text-based python game for school. They want parameters in the move_room function but that makes it loop the same room. So I tried making current_room = move_rooms(move, current_room, inventory) but if I pick up an item, the program thinks that item is the room. Can someone give me some help with this please?

```
def give_instructions():
    # print game instructions
    print("Welcome to the game!\n"
          "You were arriving home when attacked by a rival wizard,\n"
          "you wake in a strange cell where the walls meet at impossible angles.\n"
          "You have a sense of impending doom and a massive headache.\n"
          "As your head clears you realize you are in your own home.\n"
          "You must collect 7 items to defeat the wizard in your parlor.\n"
          "To move type 'go North', 'go South', 'go East' or 'go West'\n"
          "To pick up items type 'get' Item name\n"
          "To exit type 'Exit'\n")


def show_status(room, stuff, roomsli):
    # show player their current status(room, room exits and inventory)
    print('You are in {}'.format(room))
    print('Inventory:', stuff)
    if "Item" in roomsli[room]:
        print("{} is in {}".format(roomsli[room].get('Item'), room))
    for direction, room in roomsli[room].items():
        if direction != 'Item':
            print("You can exit {} to {}".format(direction, room))


def move_rooms(move, current_room, inventory):
    # controls for room movement and inventory
    if move[0] in ['Exit', 'exit']:
        # to exit game
        current_room = 'Exit'
        return current_room
    elif move[0] == 'go':
        # to change rooms or get error if not a good direction
        if move[1] not in rooms[current_room]:
            print("Invalid move\n")
        elif move[1] in rooms[current_room]:
            direction = move[1]
            current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
            return current_room

    elif move[0] == 'get':
        # to get item, add it to inventory, remove it from rooms, or error if wrong item
        if move[1] not in rooms[current_room].get("Item"):
            print("That item is not in this room\n")
        else:
            item = rooms[current_room].get('Item')
            inventory.append(item)
            del (rooms[current_room]['Item'])
            return inventory
    else:
        # if other move is entered
        print("Invalid move\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main program
    # room dictionary
    rooms = {
        'Dungeon Cell': {'West': 'Basement'},
        'Basement': {'East': 'Dungeon Cell', 'West': 'Cellar', 'North': 'Grand Hall', 'Item': 'Keys'},
        'Cellar': {'East': 'Basement', 'Item': 'Amulet'},
        'Grand Hall': {'South': 'Basement', 'East': 'Sitting Room', 'West': 'Dining Room', 'North': 'Entryway',
                       'Item': 'Staff'},
        'Sitting Room': {'North': 'Library', 'West': 'Grand Hall', 'Item': 'Cloak'},
        'Library': {'South': 'Sitting Room', 'Item': 'Book'},
        'Dining Room': {'East': 'Grand Hall', 'North': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Dusty Cupcake'},
        'Kitchen': {'South': 'Dining Room', 'East': 'Entryway', 'Item': 'Strange Potion'},
        'Entryway': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'South': 'Grand Hall', 'East': 'Parlor'},
        'Parlor': {'West': 'Entryway'},
        'Exit': {'exits the game'}
    }
    # call for instructions
    give_instructions()
    # set current room and start inventory
    current_room = "Dungeon Cell"
    inventory = []
    # main game loop
    while current_room != 'Exit' or current_room != 'Parlor':
        show_status(current_room, inventory, rooms)
        move = input("What is your move?\n").split()
        current_room = move_rooms(move, current_room, inventory)
        # exit game conditional
        if current_room == 'Exit':
            print('You exited the game. Thanks for playing!')
            break
        elif current_room == 'Parlor':
            # room conditional if wizard in room and inventory full
            if len(inventory) == 7:
                print("You use your items to defeat the wizard and regain control of your home.\n"
                      "Congratulations you have won!\n"
                      "Thanks for playing!")
                break
            # room conditional if wizard in room and inventory not full
            else:
                print("The wizard kills you as you are not prepared enough.\n"
                      "You have lost!\n"
                      "Thanks for playing!")
                break
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with your basic logic.  I see other potential problems, but it seems like the logic for taking an item from a room is ok.  So I guess you type in `get  <item>`, and the code checks to see if `<item>` is in that room.  If it isn't, it complains.  If it is, it moves it into your inventory.  That looks basically OK to me. So I don't understand your problem.

Comment: You should provide a set of inputs that demonstrate the problem you're having.  I can run your game.  I can move between rooms, but when I try to pick up an item, it It crashes on me.  The reason for exists in a few places in the `move_rooms` function.  You have to make sure that no matter what happens, that function returns a room name when it exits (returns).  In the case of `get`, you return your inventory rather than the current room.  In other cases, you return nothing at all.  If you return anything but a valid room name, your code will crash when it tries to display the current status.

Comment: There's a simple fix that you can make to `move_rooms` that will fix it to avoid crashing because the current room becomes undefined or wrong.  Take out the three `return` statements, and instead put `return current_room` at the very bottom of the function, outside of any of the `if/else` blocks, such that it is always the last line executed before the function returns.

Comment: Thanks CryptoFool that is just what I needed to fix it. It works great now!